# How to make the grooves shape

Tags: modeling

Im making computer mouse and i have made the base and i want to make the grooves cut. How can i achieve that grooves cut. Any addon or how it works. Blend file attach

**Model base model**

[image]

**Reference image**
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The fastest way may be using the ***bevel tool*** and some simple extruding and scaling operations.
[image]

Select the desired edge loop with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd>, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>. Drag the mouse to set the beveling thickness and use the <kbd>Mouse Scroll</kbd> to set the number of subdivisions. In this case I set it to 5, then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> twice and scale it a bit (<kbd>S</kbd>). This way I created a creasing edge to make the groove look smooth with the *subsurf modifier* enabled.
[image]

To make the smooth t-shaped groove just select the edge loop as pictured below and repeat the beveling proces mentioned above.
[image]

To make the recess just select some faces, extrude them inwards (<kbd>E</kbd>), then scale a bit (<kbd>S</kbd>) and translate if needed (<kbd>G</kbd>).
[image]

Comment: Thanks Im bit confuse both have given the answer and its in detail to whom i vote. Similar to this i have post 1 more question http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73501/how-to-make-the-side-grooves

Answer (score 3):

The easy way is: Go to "EDIT mode" 
Select the Lines that the groove must follow. After you select all of them, hit Ctrl-B and move your mouse until you get the width that you want.

After seeing your model, I think that you need to remake it. Using Ctrl-B to bevel won't give you the best results because you dont have any Lines that follow the grooves on the sides.

I would recommend making it all 1 mesh and modeling so that there are lines that follow the grooves in the reference images.

If you are worried about applying a different material to the "Black" and "White" parts of the surface, then don't worry. You can just select all the faces you want to be "White" and make a new material for them. Then hit "Assign" on the material tab.

Comment: I totally agree with you. His model should be retopologized to change its edge flows (or tweaked using the proportional editing). He may also want to apply the transformations to it. Anyway nice and helpful answer!

Comment: Thanks Im bit confuse both have given the answer and its in detail to whom i vote. Similar to this i have post 1 more question http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73501/how-to-make-the-side-grooves

Comment: @atek if you are wandering which question to upvote then it should be Paul's. My answer doesn't really solve the problem, it just give's some critisisme for next time :).