# making tiny edge and gaps

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I wanted to make this edges that defining the gaps between the screen and the phone body or even the body from the side of it. Should I make them 2 objects or can I make it in other way?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73468/how-to-make-the-grooves-shape

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to stay with only **one object**:

### Use bevel tool and extrusion

In Edit mode, after selecting all the edge where your tiny gap will apear, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> you will separate your edge in two edges, you can set the distance between them by moving your mouse or after that using the *Amout* value in the Bevel menu on the Left of the 3D view.

After that simply extrude the newly created face with <kbd>E</kbd> inside your mesh.

If you want to separate your mesh to work with**two objects** :

### Separate

Select all the upper part of the phone and press <kbd>P</kbd> and select 'Selection'. You will need to do some scale modification to your object.